# Парсинг без id и class

Tags: php, синтаксический-анализ

Доброго всем времени суток господа

С трудом изучаю тему парсинга. Наткнулся вот на какой нюанс. Если в коде нет id/class - зацепитсья в буквальном смысле не за что

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.***.ru');
$body_all = explode('<body>',$html);
$body_dwn = explode('<body>',$body_all[1]);
$body = $body_dwn[0];
//$body - выдернули 1 тэг
```

Одно дело найти содержимое body. Совершенно другое найти скажем 'все' ссылки. Или скажем 'все' таблицы. Может ли кто привести пример более наглядный, или быстрый?

Comment: [не мучьте себя и нас](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример для [phpQuery](http://habrahabr.ru/post/69149/)

Пример для [Simple HTML DOM](http://habrahabr.ru/post/114143/)

А если все таки "изучаете" тему парсинга, то полезным будет и сравнение [библиотек](http://habrahabr.ru/post/114323/).

Ну и для полноты картины ознакомьтесь с [XPath](http://habrahabr.ru/post/114772/)

Answer (score 0):

phpQuery достаточно удобен на мой взгляд. Особенно если знаешь Jquery.